# how to intercept WPF binding for custom processing

Tags: .net, binding

Say you have a window with 20 textboxes on it which are all bound to different BLL classes. How do I intercept a value being passed from a textbox to a property when binding with wpf? I'm looking for a generic solution instead of doing this for every property.

I can inherit from the Binding class, but is there an event in that class I can listen to whenever data is passed from an uielement to a property? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to vote on all three answers but I don't have the reputation for it. Vote for this and i'll vote for you ;)

I solved my problem thanks to you guys!

Here's what I did:

1. Create a new ValueConverter with an event SourceUpdated that fires whenever a value is passed trough it.
2. Inherit all our existing converters from it.
3. Create a new Binding class (which inherits from Binding), in the constructor see if there's a Converter already, if there isn't create one:

   ```
   if (Converter == null) {
       Converter = new GcBindingConverter();
   }

   if (Converter.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(GcBindingConverter))) {
       ((GcBindingConverter)Converter).SourceUpdated += SourceUpdatedHandler;
   }
   ```
4. On each form that needs this functionality wire the events to an event handler, I've put the handler in our modelstate:

   ```
   static void WireDirtyBindings(DependencyObject element, ModelStateBase ModelState)
   {
       Binding bb = null;
       // find bindings on elements:
       if ((object.ReferenceEquals(element.GetType, typeof(TextBox)))) {
           bb = BindingOperations.GetBinding(element, TextBox.TextProperty);
       } else if ((object.ReferenceEquals(element.GetType, typeof(ComboBox)))) {
           bb = BindingOperations.GetBinding(element, ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty);
           // other objects...
       }


   if (bb != null) {
       // wire eventhandler to event:
       doWireHandler(bb, ModelState);
   }

   // Now, recurse through any child elements
   if (element is FrameworkElement || element is FrameworkContentElement) {
       foreach (object childElement in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(element)) {
           if (childElement is DependencyObject) {
               WireDirtyBindings((DependencyObject)childElement, ModelState);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

The only thing I have to write now for each form that has lots of data input is:

```
BaseBinding.WireDirtyBindings(this, _modelState);
```

5: In the form, bind the *save changes* button's enabled state to the modelstate property that says if there are any changes. I could also use an interface for this but since we already have something like a modelstate this is a good place to put it.

This works quite nicely with just a few lines of code. Now I don't have to worry about end users making lots of changes without saving it.

Answer (score 1):

The Binding has a Converter property to which you can assign a class that implements IValueConverter. If you can inherit from binding, maybe you can set the Converter in that specialization and go on with that.

Comment: Same comment as on mattythomas2000: Yes but I already have a lot of valueconverters that do all kinds of stuff. Setting the valueconverter via a custom binding class will clear those. Isn't there a simple update event in the binding class?

Comment: In which case you may want to design a composite IValueConverter...no idea what sort of logic you want to implement when combining value modifications, but you can easily have an IValueConverter implementation that can merge several value converters into one

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution youn are looking for is a value converter. This msdn page describes how to do this -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_conversion.

Comment: Yes but I already have a lot of valueconverters that do all kinds of stuff. Setting the valueconverter via a custom binding class will clear those. Isn't there a simple update event in the binding class?

Comment: If they are all implementing the same logic (using some sort of composite IValueConverter as suggested by flq) you should be able to store the value converter in the resources and re-use it for each binding.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaking but have you tried with converter? Here's a pretty good site you can check it out:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters

Comment: Same comment as on mattythomas2000: Yes but I already have a lot of valueconverters that do all kinds of stuff. Setting the valueconverter via a custom binding class will clear those. Isn't there a simple update event in the binding class?

Comment: Didnt get why value converters arent the best way to go? U have a bunch of textboxes in your xaml.. they are binded to some viewModel or something like that.. and you wanna do what exactly? what is the main goal? and why value converters are not suitable solution?